# What are the chances of having autosomal DNA from an ancestor N generations back?

Tags: autosomal-dna

I understand that everyone carries autosomal DNA from both their mother and their father. Because there are only [a small number of crossovers per chromosome](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/how-many-recombination-events-are-there-per-generation-in-humans), I see that not everyone would carry any DNA from an ancestor several generations back.

What are the chances of a person carrying any DNA from an ancestor N generations back, where N > 1 and the simplifying assumption is made that no ancestor appears more than once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the question I answered in my blog post about 2 years ago: [Probability of No Autosomal Segments Matching](http://www.beholdgenealogy.com/blog/?p=1857)

The final table of probabilities I came up with was:

[image]

So reading the table:

- The chance of a person carrying any DNA from an ancestor 5 generations back is 99.78%
- The chance of a person carrying any DNA from an ancestor 10 generations back is 29.86%
- The chance of a person carrying any DNA from an ancestor 15 generations back is 1.61%
- etc.

The probability curve of no segments matching (which is 100% minus the chance that a descendant carries DNA) looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple resources for you:

[Concepts – Percentage of Ancestors’ DNA](https://dna-explained.com/2017/04/21/concepts-percentage-of-ancestors-dna/)

> This chart provides a summary of how many ancestors you have in each
>   generation, an approximate year they were born using a 25 year
>   generation and a 30 year generation, respectively, and how much of
>   their DNA, on average, you could expect to carry, today. You’ll notice
>   that by the time you’re in the 7th generation, you can be expected, on
>   average, to carry 0.78% meaning less than 1% of that
>   GGGGG-grandparent’s DNA.

[How much of your genome do you inherit from a particular ancestor?](https://gcbias.org/2013/11/04/how-much-of-your-genome-do-you-inherit-from-a-particular-ancestor/)

> As a rough rule of thumb the autosomes you received from (say) your
>   mother, k generations back is broken into (22+33*(k-1)) chucks, as
>   your genome comes in 22 chromosomes and there are on average 33
>   recombination events per transmitted genome. These chunks are spread
>   across your 2^(k-1) maternal ancestors. So, for example, nine
>   generations ago the autosomes you receive from (say) your mum are
>   broke, on average, into 286 large chunks, and these are spread across
>   your 256 ancestors. Thus on average each of ancestors has contributed
>   only a single block to you, and by chance it is possibly that they
>   contribute zero. This gets worse the further we go back in time, your
>   genome is broken up into more and more chunks, but this does not grow
>   as fast as your number of ancestors. This makes it increasingly likely
>   that you inherit no autosomal material from a particular ancestor.